# Facebook Graph API failing to integrate with Instagram accounts as it is not returning all Facebook Pages

Tags: facebook, instagram

After the Instagram account is connected, some of the previously listed Facebook Pages mysteriously disappear, and they do not reappear even if we disconnect the Instagram account.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently now the app requires business_management permission. There is a discussion about it here https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/336109522092665/

Comment: Try to use specific quotes or code snippets from the link, don't just use the link for nothing